# Running many small scripts throughout the day with cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a script, lets call it run-jobs.sh that I want to run. It takes in 1 argument. What I currently have set up is a cron

```
1 7 * * * /home/admin/run-jobs.sh arg1
2 7 * * * /home/admin/run-jobs.sh arg2
3 7 * * * /home/admin/run-jobs.sh arg3
```

I have many different arguments (lets say 100) to run, but I want to spread it throughout the day so it doesn't just run everything all at once. What is the best way to do this with cron, without having to make a huge cron list and have to edit it everytime? Is there something other than cron that will help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing might be to just have a wrapper script that runs once a day and sleeps between invocations, e.g.

crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /home/admin/run-all-jobs.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

run-all-jobs.sh:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
  # run the job as a background task,
  # so the job's duration doesn't throw off the timing
  run-jobs.sh "$arg" &
  # split the args evenly around 24 hours
  sleep $(( 24 * 60 * 60 / $# ))
done
```

This is easy and for simple cases will work just fine, but it's not very robust. Cron handles a lot of edge-cases for you.

---

Another option would be to dynamically generate the crontab, so you don't have to manually edit it. This example schedules each job at 15-minute intervals so it will start overlapping jobs once you have more than 96, but you can tweak it to schedule the jobs at different intervals.

generate-jobs.sh:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
  printf "%d %d * * * /home/admin/run-jobs.sh '%s'\n" \
      "$(( i / 4 ))" "$(( i % 4 ))" "${!i}"
done > /etc/cron.d/run-jobs.cron
```

This writes a file to `/etc/cron.d`, which `cron` will read from like your regular crontab.

---

A third option, which is a little more involved but possibly what you really want, is to use [`at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at). `at` is a great tool that lets you schedule tasks "at" some point in the future. With `at` you can avoid cron altogether, and just schedule your jobs whenever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for, but didn't know what it's called. I will check out 'at'. I will also see if the other 2 solutions will work for me.

Comment: I used method 1, as that is pretty simple and easy to set up. Only thing I did differently was instead of writing out all the arguments in the cron (I don't know what the limit is for line length), I made a simple txt file with all my arguments and run-all-jobs.sh loops through the file. This way it's super simple to edit the txt file when I need a new argument put in.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper script,
schedule it to run every hour,
that will run the main script with appropriate arguments depending on the hour.

```
* 7 * * * /home/admin/run-jobs-wrapper.sh
```

The wrapper could be something like:

```
case "$(date +%H)" in
01) /home/admin/run-jobs.sh arg1 ;;
02) /home/admin/run-jobs.sh arg2 ;;
...
esac
```

(Note that `date +%H` outputs the hour 0-padded.)

This way you will have something easy to understand,
easy to control in a single script that can be put under version control,
without creating a large `crontab`.
It's easy to manage too,
for example in case of machine reboots,
it's easy to know what exactly will be run,
since it simply depends on the current hour.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (variant of [dimo414 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44873173/841108), last option using `at`) would be to run a single batch command. So you would have a *single* `crontab` entry, which would use [batch(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) (a variant of `at`) to run all the hundred things. Or even call `batch` in a loop for every command.

Notice that the `batch` subsystem is limiting the load on your machine (and can be configured to have a single batched job queue). However, it does not sleep between queued batch jobs.